# View Triggers in Squirrel SQL client

Tags: squirrel-sql

I am using Squirrel SQL Client 3.7.1 version. I am unable to see the triggers available in the database. How do i see the trigger's in Squirrel SQL client tool.

I only see the tables. Could someone help me on this. Do i have to install any plug-ins ?

Comment: What are your permissions to the DB?

Comment: I am using the application user which has full access. The question is i dont see the folder name by trigger at all. I am able to see the same in MS SQL developer tool but not in SQuirrel SQL client

Comment: I've never used squirrel, but have found that different front-ends have different folder structures on where the tables, procs, views, etc are.  I should hope the documentation would reveal this.

Answer (score 1):

One of the easiest ways to do this would be to do the following:

```
select * from sys.trigger
```

This will at least allow you to see if the triggers you created are actually in the database.

In this data, you should see an `object_id`. This is used in various places throughout the database. You can find information in `sys.objects`, for example, you'll see a `parent_object_id`. From the same view, then, you'd be able to get the table for which this trigger belongs.

But what you are probably looking for is the the actual DDL used for the trigger. This can be found in the `sys.all_sql_modules` view. Simply plug in the `object_id` you got from above and look for the definition column. So, something like:

```
select definition from sys.all_sql_modules where object_id = ###
```

Hope this helps!